# jpa @version optimistic locking

Tags: java, hibernate, spring, jpa

I loaded **same entity record** on 2 separate browser window then press submit (hibernate template.**merge**), **version number incremented for both browser window**, but never caught any problem with optimistic lock..  so how to test this?

my save() look like this

```
hibernatetemplate().merge(..);
setJPAObject(null); //reset after save
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure it's not 2 browser tabs (thus same session)? Can you post your controller code?

Answer (score 1):

Two separate browsers are better for testing this.